# Authentication with Passport in separate applications API backend and APP frontend in Stack MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I created two apps in the frontend with AngularJS that consume a single API (NodeJS, Express and MongoDB).

When trying to protect the resources I need to redirect the route in the express /auth/github/callback contained in my /routes/auth.js to the frontend route in the case the page (view) desired by my user that was authenticated.

As I separated my front end from the back end, calling the /auth/github/callback route successRedirect ends up redirecting to the '/' route of the API (backend).

Follows the code:

```
app.get('/auth/github/callback',
    passport.authenticate('github', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/github',
    })
);
```

**My question is**... how can I pass to the successRedirect the route of the front end (AngularJS) and not the route of the API (Backend).

I tried the following cod, but it did not work ...

*Back-end:*

```
var session;

app.get('/auth/github', function authenticategithub(req, res, next) {
        session = '/#' + req.query.returnTo;
        next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('github'));

app.get('/auth/github/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('github', {
        successRedirect: session,
        failureRedirect: '/auth/github'
    });

});
```

*Front-end:*

```
<--partials view Auth.html -->
href="http://localhost:3003/auth/github?returnTo={{location}}"
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: So far I haven't found anything!